# Android 2.1-update1 AVD cannot make a successful connection to Charles Web Proxy 3.6

Tags: android, charles-proxy

From the Administrator Command Prompt on Windows 7, I type in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator -avd Nexus -http-proxy localhost.:8888 -port 5554 -debug-proxy
```

I return the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>server name 'localhost.' resolved to 127.0.0.1:8888
proxy_http_setup: creating http proxy service connecting to: localhost.:8888
server name 'localhost.' resolved to 127.0.0.1:8888
proxy_http_setup: creating HTTP Proxy Service Footer is (len=2):
'
'
http_service_connect: trying to connect to (null)
http_service_connect: using HTTP rewriter
tcp:(null)(252): connecting
tcp:(null)(252): connected to http proxy, sending header
tcp:(null)(252): sending 27 bytes:
>> 43 4f 4e 4e 45 43 54 20 28 6e 75 6c 6c 29 20 48    CONNECT (null) H
>> 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 0d 0a                   TTP/1.1....

tcp:(null)(252): header sent, receiving first answer line
tcp:(null)(252): received 'HTTP/1.0 503'
tcp:(null)(252): connection refused, error=503
http_service_connect: trying to connect to (null)
http_service_connect: using HTTP rewriter
tcp:(null)(332): connecting
http_service_free
```

When I open the browser in the emulator, I have the following entry in Charles:

```
null:0
Failed
CONNECT request didn't include a port: (null)
HTTP/1.1
CONNECT
/127.0.0.1
```

If I try to use my IP Address, I receive the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator -avd Nexus -http-proxy 192.234.2.90:8888 -debug-proxy

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools>server name '192.xxx.2.xx' resolved to 192.xxx.2.xx:8888
emulator: Could not connect to proxy at 192.xxx.2.xx:8888: resource temporarily unavailable !
emulator: Proxy will be ignored !
```

How do I properly run Charles against the Android emulator?

I've read the other posts about setting the proxy and port in Settings while the emulator is running, but I receive the similar errors with -debug-proxy turned on.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing similar problem and I'm running r14. Has anyone seeing this issue still? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with the latest version of the Android development tools, r12.

[This bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18715&q=proxy&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) indicates that downgrading to the emulator binary from r11 will fix the problem. Go to the [Android SDK download page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and change the '12' in the URL for your OS to '11'. Install that SDK to a separate directory from your existing SDK, and use that emulator version until Google fixes the problem.

Comment: Looks like I'm having the same problem with r12 on OS 10.6.8.  Works with r11.

Comment: I was also using r12 for Mac.  I downloaded the r11 package and just moved the emulator executable from the r11 package into my existing android-sdk-mac_86/tools directory.  Now my android apps can get on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update for anyone else looking at this, this problem has been addressed in r13

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that had been fixed at VERSION 3.9.
http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/version-history/